# Are there any reasons NOT to use angular-loader?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've worked with Angular for a little bit, but I keep managing to learn something new - today, I installed the [angular-seed](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed) project in order to give my development a little kick in the pants. I ran into the [index-async](https://github.com/angular/angular-seed/blob/master/app/index-async.html) file and learned about the angular-loader - which I hadn't used before.

I found this question, as well: [What is angular-loader.js for?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15777449/677526)

It looks as though the index-async file is using a script loader in addition to the angular module loader, which makes sense. However, I've never used this method before. (In my company, we've used [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/) to load angular modules before, and so I can understand why something like this would be easier and less cumbersome.) Yet, it also seems that I could use the loader without a third-party script loader - I could just include all of my app files, in any order, before the loader is called, without having to worry about the dependencies.

In short - when should I use angular-loader? More importantly, is there any reason NOT to use it all the time?

Comment: what am I missing here? it looks like scripts are loaded by something called `$script`. Looks like it does what requireJS does, so what role does ng-loader play?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you don't have to use it if you don't need it.

From the [Angular Docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/downloading), you use it:

> If you are loading multiple script files containing Angular modules, you can load them asynchronously and in any order as long as you load this file first. Often the contents of this file are copy&pasted into the index.html to avoid even the initial request to angular-loader.min.js. See angular-seed for an example of usage.

The reason behind is to optimize the loading time on the client-side - only load the currently needed module for the user, particularly if you have a reasonably huge app.

Comment: Yes, but there's no real downside from not using it (except for the added overhead of the angular-loader script, which isn't much). Asynchronicity aside, you don't have to worry about the order of your script tags. Is there a downside I'm missing?

Comment: @lunchmeat317 I guess I don't see the point of finding out the downside of not using it, unless you have something specific to compare with, like RequireJS?

Comment: i still don't get it... if i want to load angular files asynchronously, what role does angular-loader play? if i use requireJs, i presume, i do not have to use angular-loader ...or should i?